# How can I make a python file runnable as a script and importable as a package?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I'm still trying to get a hang of python 3 and I'm running into an issue where I can either run a .py file as a script or import it as a module, but not both.

Directory Structure

```
test/
  __init__.py
  test.py
  subwayclock/
    __init__.py
    subwayclock.py
    build/
      gen/
        __init__.py
        gtfs_realtime_pb2.py
        nyct_subway_pb2.py
      __init__.py
```

in this scenario test.py looks like this and works (rawFEED() is a function in subwayclock.subwayclock):

```
from subwayclock.subwayclock import *

print(rawFEED())
```

However, I cannot run the script directly i.e.

```
python subwayclock/subwayclock.py
```

because it gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "subwayclock.py", line 32, in <module>
    from .build.gen.gtfs_realtime_pb2 import FeedMessage
SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

HOWEVER, if I modify the import statement in subwayclock/subwayclock.py to state (i.e. with the leading '.' removed):

```
from subwayclock.subwayclock import FeedMessage
```

I can run the subwayclock.py script directly through the command line, calling the **main** function perfectly.

BUT, when I run the original test.py file, the import statement no longer works, and I get the following error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
        from subwayclock.subwayclock import *
      File "/var/www/test/subwayclock/subwayclock.py", line 32, in <module>
        from build.gen.gtfs_realtime_pb2 import FeedMessage
    ImportError: No module named 'build'
```

Can I make this script independently runnable and importable?

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you could just use *absolute imports* instead of *relative imports*, but depending on the dependencies between your modules, it could result in some odd behavior, where objects and classes are technically being defined twice (once in your `__main__` script, and once when another module imports your module)

The proper way to do this would be to create a proper python package with a `setup.py` script and use the [`console_scripts`](http://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html#the-console-scripts-entry-point) entry point feature to expose a function as a command line script.

Your project should be organized something like this.

```
/subwayclock
    /subwayclock
        __init__.py
        subwayclock.py
        ...
    setup.py
```

Your setup.py would look like this

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name='subwayclock',
      version='0.1',
      packages=find_packages(),
      zip_safe=False,
      entry_points = {
          'console_scripts': ['subwayclock_script_name=subwayclock.subwayclock:rawFEED'],
      }
)
```

Then you just install the package

```
$ python setup.py install
```

(you can also use `develop` mode so you can still work on it)

```
$ python setup.py develop
```

And you will be able to run that command line script

```
$ subwayclock_script_name
```

Answer (score 1):

I will try to describe you, how it works and, also, to help.

### Relative import

First of all, python has a number of different methods to import some.
Some of them is a relative import (`from .package import somemodule`)
 The dot means that we want to import a `somemodule` from the **current** package. That means that we should declare our package(when we import this module, we import it from the **package** , which has a name and etc.)

---

### Absolute import(maybe there is another name)

This import is used nearly everywhere in simple scripts and you must know this.
Example:

```
from app import db
```

Where `app` is a python module(`app.py` file) and `db` is a variable in it.If you want to know more, [read the docs](https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-328.html).

### ---

Solution

I don't really know a pretty way to avoid this, but if I were you, I would do like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from mypackage.module import function
else:
    from .module import function
```

Also you can run `python -m package.module.function` in simple cases, but it's not quiet a good idea.
Or you can add your package directory to a `PYTHONPATH` variable. See the [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3) to the nearly the same question.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a script from a package using the `-m` switch and the fully qualified package path

```
python -m subwayclock.subwayclock
```